# problem with if else statement in awk

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have a file like this:

```
Archaea     2   domain      
Archaea Aenigmarchaeota     11084   phylum      123
```

I am trying to use the if else statement in awk. I want to get the last column of each line and then check:

```
if{(its is a number) print (column)} else (print the previous colum)
```

I have tried this:

```
awk '{if(NF=/[0-9]/){print $(NF-1)} else{print $(NF)}}' head.txt
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `$NF ~ /[0-9]/`

Comment: `awk '{if($NF~/[0-9]/){print $NF} else{print $(NF-1)}}' head.txt` .. fixes: `NF` to `$NF` , `=` to `~` and variables to print are exchanged... @ocurran's answer is a good alternative

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need explicit If/Else logic:

```
awk '$NF ~ /[0-9]/ {print $NF; next}; {print $(NF-1)}'
```

Comment: doesn't print what OP wants

Comment: @Rahul the output appears to be consistent with the OP's textual description - their attempted solution appears to have inverted the logic